# Community Wiki: desirable or not?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I am wondering what the attitudes towards the community wiki concept are.

I personally consider it overused and mostly undesirable. I'm now probably on Joel's personal execution list but let me explain why I feel this way:

I am not a user who can farm the site 24/7 for new questions to answer. Many traditional questions get their correct answer quite quickly so in most situations I'm left with:

- voting up answers
- the occasional comment
- the even rarer exotic question that does not yet have an answer and I happen to actually know something about it
- and the kind of questions that cannot be fully answered

The only kind of questions I can reliably contribute to are the ones that - according to official policies from the founders - should be community wiki. Their reasoning is that CW fosters contribution. I don't see it that way - exactly the opposite actually.

1. Contributing to CW earns me no recognition. Don't get me wrong - virtue IS it's own reward but when you are given the choice between receiving recognition for your help or not: what do you prefer? The entire SE/SO system is so focused on rep. Everything depends on how much rep you have.
2. Anyone can answer a question but you need 100 rep to contribute to CW so you are actually shutting members out that probably would like to help.

So what am I saying about CW? What is it good for IMO? For "moderators" to condense discussions into separate posts. Nothing else comes to mind right now.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at questions like this (and the answers to these types of questions), you can see why, for all intents and purposes, there *is* no more community wiki.

So many people are *overly* fixated on "counting pennies" when it comes to the arbitrary valuation and accumulation reputation. People have long since lost sight of what wiki was *supposed* to be about. Even if you *could* explain to a new (or even an average) user the merits of foregoing ownership in lieu of allowing a broader range of editing, the rules and almost-metaphysical philosophy applied to the feature simply aren't worth the complexity, problems, and abuse it causes.

So from @Jeff's post on Meta.SO: [**Important Change**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183)

## Important change

End users can not mark questions wiki anymore, so the only appropriate way to get action on a question you believe really should be wiki, is to flag it for moderator attention.

---

A couple points..

1. **Vote-to-wiki will not be implemented**. When the answer to a problem is "let's make things arbitrarily more complicated", it is rarely the correct answer.
2. **Do not bully users into community wiki**. You can offer a carrot in the form of a comment that says "wow, I'd love to vote this up if it was community wiki" but downvoting and other nagging is not appropriate. (addendum: the community wiki flag checkbox is *not shown* for new users because they can't possibly understand it, you may potentially be nagging new users about a setting they don't even have.)
3. **If you think something should be community wiki then flag it for mod attention** with a comment to that effect. Simple.

Also, note that as of now the CW edit threshold has been reduced from 750 rep to 100 rep on all sites.

Answer (score 0):

I used it in the "Basic Dominion Strategies" thread when I contributed 3 or 4 separate answers as of way of saying:

- I am not trying to farm rep here
- Please add additional details to these strategies that I have forgotten

But I had the luxury of doing that and having a bit of rep already.