# Would my question be better off converted to Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I'm not really a fan of Community Wiki posts; I share some of the same points of view expressed in the post [Community Wiki: desirable or not?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/217/377) (both for and against). But as time goes on, the idea that my question, [*How have editions of Bang! been different from previous ones?*](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1325/377), may be better as Community Wiki is growing on me.

**Pros**

- People are likely to answer about one edition of the game at a time anyway, so this could limit the answers to one answer per edition.
- Details about each edition's differences can be "filled out" by the combined knowledge of several people, reducing the intimidation factor for those who feel they know only a little.
- Appears to be more in line with the Stack Exchange philosophy.
- The "finished product" would likely be higher quality because (most) anyone can improve any of the answers they wish to.

**Cons**

- Little-to-no incentive to add to the answers. I believe the Stack Exchange reputation model's "gaming" mechanic is a major part of Stack Exchange's success; economics and psychology (e.g., concepts related to [Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_%28psychology%29)) both support this argument.
- Barrier to entry (low-rep users can't contribute)
- No way to reward people who helped me by answering my question.

If the cons could be fixed, I would definitely request the post be converted to Community Wiki. However, assuming the *status quo* for the way Community Wiki works, I'm not sure Community Wiki status is the best way to go.

Regardless of your interest in the actual game, would you convert that question (or similar questions) to Community Wiki if it was up to you (and only you)? Why or why not? What would you define the "policy" for Community Wiki to be with regards to this type of question?

Comment: FYI - only moderators can turn questions into Community Wiki.  CW should only be used for questions that need more collaborative editing.  Your question may fall under that criteria, and I wouldn't be adverse to switching it.

Comment: @Pat, thanks. I'll modify my question to reflect the fact that I'd need to have a moderator take care of it. (As an aside, I thought I read that a post would be automatically changed to CW once it's been edited more than something like 15 times. Does that apply to questions as well?)

Comment: Yes, I think it is a sliding scale.  Around 8 edits in one day, more as time goes on.  Also a certain number of self-edits don't count.

Comment: @Pat: Thanks. I didn't know that. Also, I hope the modification is okay; it turned out to be more of an overhaul than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.