# Borderline question? Self-answer?

Tags: discussion

[Here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2240/fixing-starcraft-the-boardgame) I'm not sure if it would have been better to post the examples as a self-answer instead of including them in the question.

Actually I'm not sure if that question is an appropriate question at all, since it might or might not have a definite answer. A definite answer might come as in "hey there already are fixed rules for that, here's the link"; however if there *aren't* (yet) such rules there would probably *not* be a definitive answer, hence it might be more suited for a CW maybe?

I don't know, that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question does not meet the guidelines in our [new FAQ](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq).

I feel it does not pass the criteria:

> avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ >for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Deleting your answers would not save it.  I think it should be broken up into discrete problems that can be solved and written with a more neutral POV.  **Example**:

---

In Starcraft, the random starting positions can lead to one person sandwiched
between two others while the fourth player has 2 planets to himself.  Has it been your experience that each player still has a roughly equal chance at victory in this situation?

If not, have you tried any house rules to address this?  How did the house rule work out in actual play?

---

A [successful subjective question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) should deal in facts that can be backed up with a reference or personal experiences.  When asking for house rules, *be sure to ask only for rules that people have actually tried!*

Asking people to propose anything that tickles their fancy does not lead to quality answers.  Rather, if they have not created/used a house rule for a particular situation, that person should be encouraged to vote/answer as to whether they think a house rule is needed and to "back it up" with **actual play experience**.

FYI - Community Wiki is not a solution for very many problems.  It should only be used for resources that need to be editing by the community at large.

Comment: Ooh, good idea splitting them! I'll definitely do that (sooner or later)

Answer (score 1):

I think the question overall is good, although I would have added *what* aspect of combat, research, and starting positions you don't like. The argument you advance against them holds against any "house rules" question, and I think those are just about the most interesting questions there are on the site. Yes, they're subjective, but they can definitely be [good subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Community wiki is only applied to some [very specific situations](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217/community-wiki-desirable-or-not).

To answer your other question, I would personally have preferred self-answers to part-of-the-question answers, but I don't know if the community agrees.